# В БД узнать сколько записей принадлежит определенным полям

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Я не знаю правильно или нет указал заголовок. Суть в чем, есть таблица с полями: Дата, id_комнаты, id_человека. 
Нужно вывести Дату и комнату в которой находилось больше 15 человек,
эти поля являются составными ключами, повторятся дата и id_комнаты не могут в принципе т.е. не может быть два поля с датой 1.10.2017 и id_комнаты 10 но разным кол-вом человек... я походу совсем запутался

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Дата, id_комнаты
FROM Люди
GROUP BY Дата, id_комнаты having count(id_человека) > 15
```

но я не понимаю как это работает...